# Processing after Worker has finished

Tags: concurrency, javafx

Calling a method on a REST API produces a `javafx.concurrent.Worker` object.

```
final Worker<ObservableList<ProductBrand>> retrieve = listDataProvider.retrieve();
```

I would like some operations to take place after `Worker` has done its work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a listener with the `Worker`'s `state` property and handle the state transitions:

```
retrieve.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        ObservableList<ProductBrand> result = retrieve.getValue();
        // etc...
    } else if (newState == Worker.State.FAILED) {
        Throwable exception = retrieve.getException();
        /// etc...
    }
    // handle other states (READY, SCHEDULED, RUNNING, CANCELLED) if needed
});
```

Note that this callback will be executed on the FX Application Thread, so you can safely modify the state of elements of the scene graph here.